# QString to short using toShort

Tags: qt, qstring, qlineedit

I want to convert QString to short.when I try this code

```
ui->lineEdit->text().toShort();
```

It works well for text = 20 but it returns "0" for value = 20.5.

but I need value = 20. how can I solve it?

Comment: don't allow decimal points in the lineEdit

Comment: QString::number(ui->lineEdit->text().toInt()).toShort();

Comment: I tried this code but still have problem

inline __int16 GetInteger16FromStatic(QLineEdit* lineEdit)
{
 QString text;
 __int16 nValue = 0;

 nValue = QString::number(lineEdit->text().toDouble()).toShort();
 
 
 return nValue;

}

Answer (score 4):

The reason that 0 is returned is because a decimal point is an invalid character for the `short` data type.

If you want to be able to convert floating-point numbers from `QString` to integers, you need to convert your text to a `float` or `double` first, then use normal rounding/truncation to convert to `short`.

Answer (score 0):

use that convertion string:

```
ui->lineEdit->text()->split(".")[0].toShort(0,10);
```