# qstring to short format for qlineedit

Tags: qt, qstring, qlineedit

I tried this code but still have problem for `QString` to short value for example it work well for text = `20` but it return `0` for value = `20.5`.

but I need value=`20`. how can I solve it?

```
inline __int16 GetStaticToInteger(QLineEdit* lineEdit) {
    QString text; __int16 nValue = 0;
    nValue = QString::number(lineEdit->text().toDouble()).toShort();
    return nValue;
}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133389/qstring-to-short-using-toshort

Answer (score 2):

'20.5' is not a valid text representation for an integer value. You can check this:

```
QString str("20.5");

bool ok;
short s = str.toShort(&ok);

qDebug() << ok
```

The output will be 'false'.

If you need an integer value you can do this:

```
short s = str.toDouble();
```

If you need your value rounded to the nearest integer use `qRound`:

```
short s = qRound(str.toDouble());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have made it to complicated.

```
inline __int16 GetInteger16FromStatic(QLineEdit* lineEdit) {
    QString text; __int16 nValue = qRound(lineEdit->text().toDouble());
    return nValue;
}
```

Also Qt provides types with defined size, like `qint16` to be compiler/platform independent, so you don't have to use `__int16`.